# Output placement in C using tabs problem

Tags: c

How can I make sure not to happen like this? Is there any way to show exact place by numbers?

```
Name            UID     GID     Dir     Host
root    0       0       /root
paingpyi        500     500     /home/paingpyi  192.168.12.1
paingpyi        500     500     /home/paingpyi  192.168.12.1
```

Code is

```
printf("Name \t\tUID \tGID \tDir \tHost\n");
printf("%s \t\t%d \t%d \t%s \t%s \n",up->ut_user,pw->pw_uid,pw->pw_gid,pw->pw_dir,up->ut_host);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `printf` width specifiers are more appropriate for this kind of tasks than `\t`. You should  have a look into the 'field width' section of [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Comment: specifically, he should use something like `%-16.16s` for strings and `%-8d` for integers

Comment: What if I also want to format for Header? I don't have any $s or $d for Header line. What shall I do?

Comment: @Devyn you can use something such as `printf("%-16s%-8s%-8s\n", "Name", "UID", "GID")`

Comment: Wow.. I've never thought like that. That's a great answer :) Thanks a lot for everyone!